# How to increase performance of Azure Data Factory Pipeline?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have Azure Data Factory pipeline, which are running Lookup(SQL Selects) and Copy Data(Inserts) in ForEach for 5000-1000 times. I want to execute pipeline nightly, but currently it takes more than 8 hours to finish. Each iteration takes 15min.

I can see from Azure SQL that CPU, RAM, IO load Metrics are ok.

I'm using Self-Hosted Integration runtime.

What I can do to speed up Azure Data Factory processing?
How I can find bottleneck of solution and how to fix?

Comment: Sounds like a lot of overhead. Can you give a more detailed explanation of the pipeline? Is the Lookup inside the Foreach? What types are the Copy source and Sink? How large are the payloads? Are all the resources (ADF, Lookup target, source and sink) in the same data center? Is the Foreach sequential?

Answer (score 0):

You can enhance the scale of processing by the following approaches:

1. You can scale up the self-hosted IR, by increasing the number of concurrent jobs that can run on a node.
   Scale up works only if the processor and memory of the node are being less than fully utilized.
2. You can scale out the self-hosted IR, by adding more nodes (machines).

Here are [Performance tuning steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#performance-tuning-steps) that can help you to tune the performance of your service.

You can follow this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-troubleshooting) to identify and resolve the bottleneck.